# Logback: out-of-the-box properties

Tags: java, logback

Where should I look to see the default logback properties, e.g. user.home?

It is great that I can use external file, System and environment to load properties, but are there any out-of-box ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`user.home` is a Java system property, not a logback property. You can see the rest of them with `System.out.println(System.getProperties());` or using JConsole on a running JVM.

Apart from that, I think there are only `HOSTNAME` and `CONTEXT_NAME` defined by Logback: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#variableSubstitution

Comment: it seems that you don't understand the question, or I don't understand the answer. =) I meant what is the list of the predefined properties like user.home to use like ${user.home}?

Comment: @Dmitry I guess you don't understand your question.

Answer (score 3):

`user.home` is not logback specific, they come from java.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html